# Tracing Pattern On Fabric Using Laundry Marker

Tags: drawing, digital-printing

two short questions:  I want to transfer a pattern similar to this to fabric: [image]

Since I really like the aesthetic of vintage camouflage clothes, I want to go for a similar look.  I noticed that camouflage is often printed on darker fabric, e.g. green or brown, and also the ink seems to penetrate the fabric deeper than it is the case in screen print and it lets the graphics appear a bit blurred around the edges, which I also like.  So maybe someone can recommend me a printing method for this (possibly reactive dyes?) but I also like the idea of transferring the pattern by hand, even if it might look a bit more DIY, I want to give it a try.  So I thought about getting the [Edding 8040 laundry marker](https://www.edding.com/products/edding-8040-laundry-marker/) (which is advertised as boil-proof, which makes me think that it will also penetrate the fabric quite well) in red and black and draw on dark blue fabric.

The only question, what's the cheapest way to transfer a blueprint so to say of the pattern to the fabric, which I can then trace with the marker and which will wash out without any traces?  So it really doesn't matter how it looks as long as it gives me enough information to trace it out.  Also it shouldn't keep the  marker ink from soaking into the fabric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual method used to print on darker fabrics is to use screen printing.

The process usually involves printing a white underbase prior to overprinting in colour. The reason for this is because coloured inks are typically semi-transparent, so darker coloured fabrics would just show through the ink, making brighter colours just look too dark.

An opaque white underbase helps prevent the problem.

There's an in-depth technical explanation and demonstration on this screen printing video on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wFgHv7q6AY&ab_channel=LeeStuart

As you will see from the video, screen printing is a complex process and there's considerable outlay in equipment and skills to be learnt. Maybe best left to the professionals.

If you were to attempt it at home, I think you'd probably need to look into using something like opaque fabric paints, but I have literally no clue about that kind of thing. Perhaps this question would be better asked on Arts & Crafts Stack Exchange.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer!  Sorry, the image I included might be misleading, but I definitely don't want to print bright colors on dark fabric, the image is just about the general kind of pattern.  I want the print to look more like [this](https://historypreser-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/buzz-rickson-br14788-m-1943-frog-skin-camo-field-jacket-collar-tab-wo.jpg), but maybe only two colors.  I'd assume that here the fabric already came in the beige color and the pattern is not screen printed but rotary printed or something similar.

Comment: @fweth OK, then screen printing without a without a white underbase might work.  But this might not be feasible for a DIY project. I've updated my answer to include possibly using fabric paints, but this is beyond my experience in print, and probably better asked somewhere like Arts & Crafts Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the  hint about Arts & Craft, I didn't know this community exists.  I will delete the question and reask there, is this the correct procedure?  If I accept your answer and delete afterwards, you won't get reputation points, right?

Comment: @fweth - don't think you can delete it now that I've answered. You could perhaps flag your question and ask the mods to migrate it for you, although might be too late for that too. I'm not sure. Sorry.